# Fetch the state attribute from YAML using Cpp

Tags: c++

How can I iterate over the above YAML file using C++ ([yaml-cpp][1]) so that I can verify if each group (`testA`, `testB` and `testC`) has change in state or not?

If state attribute is off then print the next elements in the group i.e. `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, `a5`. If no state attribute is provided then print state attribute is missing.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: `YAML::Node` has `begin()` and `end()` and type checks. It's pretty well prepared for what you want done.

Comment: @ChrisMM Please check the above code which i have used.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Its entering catch block for every variable.

Comment: @Chandu: Is this line compiling? `for (auto element: YAML::Node tlist["test"])`

Comment: @Chandu It should be throwing an exception in `LoadFile("example.yaml")` since it's not valid yaml as pointed out in Azeems answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML that you've posted is invalid. You can use online YAML validators to lint it e.g.:

- https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator
- https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator

Here's your valid YAML file (observe the indentation of last element):

```
test:
  - testA:
    - state: off
    - name: a1
    - name: a2
    - name: a3
    - name: a4
  - testB:
    - state : on
    - name: b1
  - testC:
    - name: c1
```

You can simply dump it on terminal like this:

```
const auto yaml = YAML::LoadFile( "example.yaml" );
std::cout << YAML::Dump( yaml ) << '\n';
```

---

This line in your code

```
for (auto element: YAML::Node tlist["test"])
```

should be

```
for (auto element : tlist["test"])
```

---

After these changes, you can proceed with the rest of your logic.

Here's a small example with valid YAML file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main()
{
    const auto yaml = YAML::LoadFile( "example.yaml" );    
    const auto test = yaml["test"];
    for ( const auto& t : test )
    {
        for ( const auto& i : t )
        {
            const auto tname = i.first.as<std::string>();
            std::cout << tname << '\n';

            const auto ts = t[tname];
            for ( const auto& j : ts )
            {
                if ( j["state"] )
                {
                    const auto state = j["state"].as<std::string>();
                    std::cout << "- state: " << state << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
testA
- state: off
testB
- state: on
testC
```

For further information, refer to the [tutorial](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial).

Comment: @Chandu: You're welcome! Please refer to the library's documentation as much as you can. Some APIs are not so intuitive at first. There are similar issues filed on the repo also. You may look at those as well.